# DataTable headers remaining same even if the data source changes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html-table, datatables

I am using **jQuery Datatable** to populate table in **angular1** app.
In My app, I have 2  tabs, lets say tab1 and tab2.
in tab1 I have a table with column heading col1 and col2. similarly in tab2 I have a table with column heading col3 and col4. I am using the scope variable `$scope.columnHeading` to pass the column headings, meaning if I click tab1,

```
 $scope.columnHeading = ["col1","col2"]
```

and if I click tab2 then,

```
$scope.columnHeading = ["col3","col4"].
```

table structure is

```
<table id="test" class="table" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="item in columnHeading" ><label>item</label></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  //body data
</tbody>
```

Now the issue is, suppose I am clicking *tab1*, then table will have heading *col1* and *col2* and it will remain throughout tabs, meaning even if I click tab2, column headers will not change.

If I remove **Datatable** from app, it will work fine. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you have `<div id="debug">{{columnHeading}}</div>` and click your tabs, can you see the change in the debug element? With and without the datatable? (Also, a jsfiddle or something of the sort would help a lot in sorting things out.)

Comment: This seems really peculiar. Not the problem but the approach itself.  Why are you trying to change the column headers on tab change? When you are using DataTables, and dealing with columns not known before creation, the best approach is to define headers by the `columns` options. And if you want to change column headers, you must reinitialise. BTW I see no DataTables code whatsoever; Also BTW: You need to use correct, valid HTML, headers are defined by `<th>`  not `<td>` ...

Comment: with/without DataTable , I can see the changes in columnHeading using  `<div  id="debug">{{columnHeading}}</div>`